Where do I add the google-services.json for a compose multiplatform project?
I have created a project using the Kotlin Multiplatform Wizard.
I have a project in Firebase and have downloaded the google-services.json file.
Do I place this file at the same level as composeApp or at the level of androidApp?
I have tried adding these files at both locations but always get this exception -
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.github.ksalil.gamehub. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
I also added the FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) as suggested in the exception in onCreate() of my application class.
This is the project structure

Where do I add the google-services.json for a compose multiplatform project?

I was missing this plugin, id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.2" apply false in the respective build files.
After adding it I can access Firebase in my app.


Where do I add the google-services.json for a compose multiplatform project?

The google-services.json file should be placed in a Compose Multiplatform project inside:
root/android/app

On the other hand, the GoogleService-Info.plist file should be placed in a Compose Multiplatform project inside:
root/ios/app/KotlinMultiplatformApp


I have added the project structure to the question. I do not have the /android/app path.

Did you do this? This article might also help.

Hey Salil. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

The article seems to use the project template created from Android Studio which has the androidApp, shared and iosApp modules. I have used the template from the Kotlin multiplatform wizard and the project structure there is different which I have shared as a screenshot.

I found this article that has the same structure but it is not working for me.
https://funkymuse.dev/posts/kmp-firebase/#add-configuration-for-android

"it is not working for me" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

The same exception which was also part of the question -
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.github.ksalil.gamehub. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
